Laravel vite add css using js import statement vs straight add it in the vite.config.js
Below are two different methods that I can choose from to include css file in my laravel app. Is there any pro/con in choosing one vs the other?

Method 1

   - Add the following line in the app.js 
     import '../css/app.css' 

   - In vite.config.js, specify only the app.js in the laravel input array
         laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),


Method 2

   - In vite.config.js, specify both the app.js and app.css in the laravel input array
         laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'],
            refresh: true,
        }),

